# make a line that is the minimum of all entries up to that point in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Right now I have a pandas df and a plot like this

```
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x, y)
```

How can I add a line that is the minimum of all entries up to that point?

Comment: Use function `cummin()` to calculate the cumulative minimum, then plot the results on the same chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to plot the cumulative minimum of the y points. Depending on what format they are stored in, there are several options. In case `y` is a list or array, you may do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(34)

x = np.linspace(0,100)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(len(x)))

plt.plot(x,y)

ymin = [min(y[:i]) for i in range(1,len(x)+1)]

plt.plot(x,ymin)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

apply [cummin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cummin.html) function on the relevant column, then plot it

Comment: Should I write cummin(y), and then ```matplotlib.pyplot.plot(cummin(y))```?

Comment: Depends on what is `y`. If it's a column in your df, you can even write y.cummin().plot()